# XCode 4.6 - Document.xib + MainMenu.xib action from MainMenu shall set outlet in Document.xib

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I have a MainMenu which should call an action in an AppController which then should send a message to an outlet of the MainDocument.

When I instantiate an object in Interface Builder in MainMenu.xib this cannot send a message to an outlet in a different xib, as far I understand.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the default items in the menu are hooked up to that strange "First Responder" placeholder that you see in Interface Builder. Any action message you send to it will get [sent through the responder chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html) which is probably what you want. Read that linked document for more information.

(It's rare that you'd need to hook up an outlet across multiple `.xib` files.)

Comment: Yes I tried that - but the menu stays greyed out now. Any Idea?

Comment: The menu items are greyed out now, not the menu. Do you have a further idea?

Comment: That probably means your object implementing the action isn't properly in the responder chain.

Comment: The object implementing the action is a simple AppController. How do I add this object into the responder chain?

Comment: Both the main window's delegate and the app delegate are always in the responder chain.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking to notify the MainDocument object when you click on a menu item in the MainMenu? If that is the case, one way is to use NSNotification to post the message. You can review the Apple Docs on how to do this here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i

Comment: Please don't! This leads to a bunch of extra boilerplate code that's totally unnecessary! Cocoa has a standard way of handling this, and to go around it is to make extra work for yourself.